# What is a Spring AOP 'advice'?

Tags: spring

As the question states.

What is an 'advice'? More importantly, what does it even mean (semantics)? 
What's the etymology of 'advice' in the Spring context?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: I know all that. I still don't know the etymology of the word 'advice' in the Spring context. Sure, it's an action taken by an aspect at a particular join point. Sure, it intercepts around certain points in the code. That explains the how, it doesn't explain the what. I need to know why the Spring developers chose the word 'advice' for this, because it's not making any sense to me. If I can't relate to it, if I can't make relationships between those concepts in my mind, I can't understand it. So I still don't know what it etymologically means.

Answer (score 2):

It's an established standard term of aspect-oriented programming. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_in_aspect-oriented_programming):

> In aspect and functional programming, advice describes a class of
>   functions which modify other functions when the latter are run; it is
>   a certain function, method or procedure that is to be applied at a
>   given join point of a program.
>
> [...]
>
> The term advice goes back to the term advising as introduced by Warren Teitelman in his PhD thesis in 1966.

Comment: Still explains too much of 'how' and 'what'. I'm looking for the 'why' in this. I have searched dictionary.com and I have found this: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/advice?s=t : "2) a communication, especially from a distance, containing information 3) an official notification". Some synonyms included: 'to admonish' which in turn means: "to urge to a duty; remind". In that context I could see 'to advise' as reminding another piece of code of something "Hey, you threw an Exception; you got logged". Distant communication: disconnected entity providing information (log()).

Comment: Also found this: "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/counsel?s=ts" 'to advise' means 'to give counsel'. The word 'counsel' itself has one of these meanings: "advice; opinion or instruction given in directing the judgment or conduct of another.". I suppose that makes sense in a way. A method (instruction) that directs the conduct (way of acting) of another method.